# How to upgrade Fuse Servicemix 4.2.0 to 4.4.0

Tags: upgrade, apache-servicemix, fuse

Has any one attempted this before? I would like to know how to upgrade from 4.2 to 4.4 bearing in mind that there are exisiting services on the latter, which I hope will still work on the newly upgraded 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

FuseSource offers migration guides. If you are a FuseSource subscriber then I suggest to use that channel to help with the upgrade.